# How can I solve $(1+2i)^i$.

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

The question is how can I solve 
$$(1+2i)^i$$
Thanks for hints.

Comment: Please add a bit more context. Such as your own effort. You may wish to consider some similar things, such as $$i^{i}=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

Comment: How did you try to solve it?

Comment: Put $1 + 2i$ into polar coordinates.  $1 + 2i = r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta) = e^{r + \theta i}$  then $(1+2i)^i = e^{-\theta + ri} = \frac 1{e^{\theta}}(\cos r + i \sin r)$.

Comment: I don't think "solve" is the right word here?... maybe "expand" or "simplify" or ...

Answer (score 3):

$(1+2i) = \sqrt 5 (\cos\theta + i \sin \theta)$
where $\theta = \arctan 2$

now for the tricky part!

$\sqrt 5 (\cos\theta + i \sin \theta) = e^{\sqrt 5 + i\theta}$

This is Euler's identity.

$(\sqrt 5 (\cos\theta + i \sin \theta))^i = e^{(\sqrt 5 + i\theta)^i} =e^{(-\theta + i \sqrt 5)} = e^{-\arctan 2}(\cos \sqrt 5 + i \sin \sqrt 5) $